# Equivalence of norms of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have proved this result:
$$\sup\{\|Tu\|: \|v\| = 1\} = \sup\{\|Tu\|: \|v\| <1\}$$ when $T$ is a bounded linear operator.

My question is: what happens when $T$ is an unbounded line operator? Is equality maintained?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that both of those $\sup$s will be equal to $\infty$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Of course I thought so but any idea how to prove it?

Comment: If there are vectors $v$ with $\|v\|<1$ and $\|T(v)\|$ arbitrarily large, then you replace those vectors $v$ with $\frac v{\|v\|}$ and then $\left\|T\left(\frac v{\|v\|}\right)\right\|$ is even greater than $\|T(v)\|$. And if, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some vector $v$ with $\|v\|=1$ and $\|T(v)\|\geqslant n^2$, then $\left\|\frac vn\right\|<1$ and $\left\|T\left(\frac vn\right)\right\|\geqslant n$.

Comment: The equality is only true if the vector space is not equal to $\{0\}$.